# How do you kill all the entities that enter a certain radius except for villagers and players?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I have been trying to make a safezone for a map. I want to make it kill any mobs that come into the safezone except for villagers (for trading) and players within a certain radius.

I have looked at quite a few of the questions on here and haven't found the answer I'm looking for. Some people suggested using scoreboards and I find them extremely complicated. I don't know if they have a range function. I have seen some people say to make multiple kill commands and string them up, but I can't do that because I have the Mo' Creatures mod installed.

I am running Minecraft 1.10.2.

If anyone needs extra info on something comment and ask about it as I don't know what else to say in the question.
Please don't be harsh like some people have been to me in the past.

Answer (score 4):

`execute @e[type=!player,x=,y=,z=,r=] ~ ~ ~ kill @s[type=!villager]`
Just add the coordinates and the radius you need in the first target selector.

Comment: Very clever way to do it in one command, bravo!

Comment: @Bot-Ethan If you get an error message, maybe you're playing in an older version? If yes, then you should mention that in the question.

Comment: Btw, in 1.13 you should be able to just write "`type=!player,type=!villager`". But not in 1.12.2.